# Write lists to csv

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to write 2 lists I have to a csv. My current code will only write the first writerow call. My goal is to write names[0], table[0], names[ 1 ], table[ 1 ] etc etc

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import csv


url = "http://www.thegreyhoundrecorder.com.au/form-guides/lismore/longform/62384/1"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

names = soup.find_all("span", class_="dogName")
table = soup.find_all("table", class_="longForm")


with open("test.csv", "a") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for n,t in zip(names, table):
        writer.writerow([n.get_text()])
        writer.writerow([t.get_text()])
```

output = the result of writer.writerow([n.get_text()])

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but I'm not sure what you want to do with the tables.  That's a big blob of table HTML.  Here's an example that makes sense to me.  Modify as you see fit.  The trick is to open the file using newline and encoding parameters (see the docs for csv.reader/writer), and writing everything you want in one line as one list passed to writerow.  Also the source site must have changed and I got a 404 error, so I just picked another page.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import csv

url = "http://www.thegreyhoundrecorder.com.au/form-guides/addington/long-form/62423/1"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

names = soup.find_all("span", class_="dogName")
table = soup.find_all("table", class_="longForm")
headers = ['Name'] + [h.get_text() for h in table[0].find_all('th')]

#patch because headers are wonky
headers[1] = 'Day'
headers[2] = 'Date'

with open("test.csv",'w',newline='',encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    for n,t in zip(names, table):
        for row in t.find_all('tr')[:-1]: # less one row because it is blank
            cols = [col.get_text() for col in row.find_all('td')]
            writer.writerow([n.get_text().strip()]+cols)
```

Output:

```
Name,Day,Date,Fin,Box,Mgn,Trk,Dist,Grd,Time,Win T,BON,Sect,In Run,Wgt,SP,Winner / Second
TUBBY KEVIE,FRI,07/09/18,1ST,(2),4.70,CCH,295,C12,17.37,17.37,17.29,5.93,111,34.0,$9.5,GOLDSTAR POWER
TUBBY KEVIE,TUE,11/09/18,4TH,(5),4.30,OTG,310,C2,19.03,18.76,18.56,N/A,444,34.4,$7.5,HOMEBUSH SKIP
TUBBY KEVIE,THU,13/09/18,1ST,(2),0.70,CCH,295,C3,17.61,17.61,17.02,N/A,311,33.1,$5.9,DUSKY BREW
TUBBY KEVIE,TUE,18/09/18,4TH,(1),4.10,SOU,390,C3,23.16,22.90,22.36,N/A,434,34.7,$3,HOMEBUSH SKIP
TUBBY KEVIE,TUE,25/09/18,6TH,(1),6.60,OTG,310,C45,19.08,18.66,18.60,N/A,566,35.3,$17.1,SERGESS
TUBBY KEVIE,THU,27/09/18,4TH,(4),6.20,CCH,295,C4,17.73,17.34,17.17,N/A,544,34.9,$14.6,OSKITZ
TUBBY KEVIE,TUE,02/10/18,5TH,(3),7.00,SOU,390,C4,23.32,22.88,22.84,N/A,845,35.0,$10.9,SOZIN'S BLUE
TUBBY KEVIE,THU,04/10/18,6TH,(2),4.50,CCH,295,C4,17.57,17.29,17.01,N/A,666,34.4,$7.9,IT'S THAT FRESH
ZUGZWANG,TUE,24/04/18,3RD,(5),1.30,SOU,390,C3,22.93,22.85,22.45,N/A,323,32.4,$10.3,STAR BUCKING
ZUGZWANG,TUE,08/05/18,1ST,(8),1.50,SOU,390,C3,23.09,23.09,22.17,N/A,421,32.5,$9,MAGIC MIKE
ZUGZWANG,TUE,15/05/18,2ND,(7),1.00,OTG,310,C4,18.67,18.61,18.16,N/A,432,33.3,$19.2,GOTCHA MAGENTA
ZUGZWANG,TUE,22/05/18,7TH,(7),6.80,SOU,390,C34,23.10,22.67,22.53,N/A,687,33.3,$9.2,COSMIC RICHIE
ZUGZWANG,TUE,29/05/18,7TH,(2),7.60,OTG,310,C4,18.91,18.43,18.27,N/A,577,33.0,$12.8,COSMIC JASE
ZUGZWANG,TUE,05/06/18,5TH,(7),4.70,SOU,390,C34,23.03,22.73,22.54,N/A,555,33.3,$10.5,DETECTIVE DASH
ZUGZWANG,TUE,12/06/18,6TH,(7),9.40,OTG,310,C3,19.19,18.60,18.51,N/A,576,33.0,$15.9,DEBBIE BAXTER
ZUGZWANG,THU,04/10/18,4TH,(3),6.80,CCH,295,C3,17.80,17.37,17.01,N/A,434,33.5,$18.1,ZIPPING LANCE
KETCHIKAN KIM,THU,09/08/18,8TH,(3),15.60,CCH,295,C1,18.32,17.34,17.12,N/A,788,27.2,$2.4,OPAWA LAWSEY
KETCHIKAN KIM,TUE,14/08/18,6TH,(2),6.10,OTG,310,C1,19.08,18.70,18.44,N/A,566,27.1,$2.6,CHIEF DOUG
KETCHIKAN KIM,TUE,21/08/18,7TH,(6),6.60,CCH,295,C1,17.92,17.50,17.37,N/A,557,27.1,$2.7,ZIRCON
KETCHIKAN KIM,TUE,18/09/18,5TH,(4),2.20,CCH,295,C1,17.79,17.65,17.23,N/A,455,27.2,$8.8,DAGNY
KETCHIKAN KIM,TUE,25/09/18,3RD,(4),4.30,OTG,310,C1,19.18,18.91,18.60,N/A,333,26.8,$4.9,BENDER TRUTH
KETCHIKAN KIM,TUE,02/10/18,1ST,(2),5.70,CCH,295,C1,17.26,17.26,17.25,5.90,111,26.6,$3.2,GOLDSTAR AVALON
KETCHIKAN KIM,TUE,09/10/18,7TH,(5),17.00,OTG,310,C2,19.55,18.48,18.48,N/A,877,27.2,$2.9,CHASING FAME
KETCHIKAN KIM,FRI,12/10/18,1ST,(1),0.70,CCH,295,C2,17.77,17.77,17.59,6.04,111,26.9,$2.4,OPAWA VIKING
HALF SILVER FERN,THU,30/08/18,7TH,(6),11.60,CCH,295,C3,18.15,17.42,17.00,N/A,887,26.6,$18.4,SHADY BANJO
HALF SILVER FERN,TUE,04/09/18,6TH,(6),8.10,SOU,390,C3,22.99,22.48,22.48,N/A,866,26.8,$35.1,DYNA KUSHIDA
HALF SILVER FERN,FRI,07/09/18,1ST,(2),2.50,CCH,295,C12,17.68,17.68,17.29,6.00,111,26.9,$9.1,JEALOUS MUCH
HALF SILVER FERN,THU,13/09/18,4TH,(5),3.90,CCH,295,C3,17.63,17.38,17.02,N/A,344,26.8,$21.2,SETTLE GRETTEL
HALF SILVER FERN,TUE,18/09/18,6TH,(5),5.70,SOU,390,C3,23.26,22.90,22.36,N/A,766,27.2,$10.9,HOMEBUSH SKIP
HALF SILVER FERN,THU,20/09/18,2ND,(6),2.70,CCH,295,C3,17.85,17.68,17.16,N/A,222,27.4,$25.6,BARELLEN PANTHER
HALF SILVER FERN,TUE,09/10/18,7TH,(6),7.10,OTG,310,C3,19.24,18.79,18.48,N/A,787,26.9,$30.9,DISOBEDIENCE
HALF SILVER FERN,THU,11/10/18,7TH,(7),7.20,CCH,295,C3,17.88,17.43,17.13,N/A,877,27.0,$25.2,FIRED UP JED
SIERRA DELTA,FRI,17/08/18,5TH,(7),8.20,CCH,295,C2,17.89,17.37,17.21,N/A,565,27.4,$7.3,ZIPPING LANCE
SIERRA DELTA,FRI,24/08/18,6TH,(4),9.50,CCH,295,C2,18.02,17.42,17.40,N/A,666,27.1,$5.4,BOSTON POWERS
SIERRA DELTA,FRI,31/08/18,8TH,(4),9.00,CCH,295,C2,18.07,17.50,17.35,N/A,438,26.7,$7.8,HI HO TONTO
SIERRA DELTA,TUE,11/09/18,1ST,(3),2.00,CCH,295,C1,17.49,17.49,17.32,N/A,211,26.3,$3.9,WHITE NOT WONG
SIERRA DELTA,FRI,21/09/18,1ST,(5),1.70,CCH,295,C2,17.51,17.51,17.36,5.95,111,26.7,$4.9,NATIVE SCOUT
SIERRA DELTA,TUE,25/09/18,8TH,(5),10.40,OTG,310,C2,19.26,18.60,18.60,N/A,588,26.3,$2.9,IT'S A JOKE
SIERRA DELTA,THU,27/09/18,7TH,(2),9.50,CCH,295,C3,17.97,17.37,17.17,N/A,587,26.5,$9.1,DIZZY BANJO
SIERRA DELTA,THU,04/10/18,8TH,(4),41.60,CCH,295,C3,19.99,17.37,17.01,N/A,5f8,26.2,$17,ZIPPING LANCE
JITTERBUG JEWEL,THU,03/05/18,2ND,(6),3.00,CCH,295,CNZ05H,17.52,17.33,17.11,N/A,432,30.4,$15.3,FLOWER BOMB
JITTERBUG JEWEL,THU,10/05/18,4TH,(8),1.80,CCH,295,C23,17.58,17.47,17.28,N/A,544,30.9,$4.6,HOMEBUSH BODEN
JITTERBUG JEWEL,THU,14/06/18,8TH,(5),10.30,CCH,295,C3,18.01,17.36,17.19,N/A,888,32.2,$6.1,SARAYA JAYDE
JITTERBUG JEWEL,THU,13/09/18,4TH,(3),1.70,CCH,295,C3,17.72,17.61,17.02,6.07,134,33.1,$6.3,TUBBY KEVIE
JITTERBUG JEWEL,FRI,21/09/18,2ND,(8),0.70,CCH,295,C2,17.50,17.46,17.36,N/A,222,33.0,$4.2,MY BRO MICHAEL
JITTERBUG JEWEL,FRI,28/09/18,3RD,(7),2.70,CCH,295,C2,17.57,17.40,17.36,N/A,333,32.9,$2.5,DUNK IT
JITTERBUG JEWEL,FRI,05/10/18,1ST,(3),0.70,CCH,295,C2,17.36,17.36,17.27,5.85,111,32.8,$3,GOLDSTAR JAY JAY
JITTERBUG JEWEL,THU,11/10/18,2ND,(4),0.10,CCH,295,C3,17.50,17.49,17.13,N/A,322,32.6,$4.2,GO MARSHA GO
SMASH BOMBER,THU,05/07/18,6TH,(6),7.70,CCH,295,C34,18.06,17.57,17.16,N/A,766,28.1,$12.8,SOZIN'S BLUE
SMASH BOMBER,THU,02/08/18,7TH,(7),10.20,CCH,295,C34,17.91,17.27,17.21,N/A,877,29.2,$15.8,CASH A ROO
SMASH BOMBER,FRI,10/08/18,2ND,(2),5.70,CCH,295,C3,17.75,17.39,17.39,N/A,222,28.9,$6.1,PRINCELY GOLD
SMASH BOMBER,THU,30/08/18,8TH,(7),12.10,CCH,295,C3,18.18,17.42,17.00,N/A,778,28.1,$9.5,SHADY BANJO
SMASH BOMBER,THU,13/09/18,5TH,(4),2.40,CCH,295,C3,17.76,17.61,17.02,N/A,555,29.3,$6.7,TUBBY KEVIE
SMASH BOMBER,THU,27/09/18,2ND,(1),0.50,CCH,295,C3,17.59,17.56,17.17,5.99,112,29.3,$5.3,MY BRO MICHAEL
SMASH BOMBER,THU,04/10/18,3RD,(4),6.20,CCH,295,C3,17.57,17.18,17.01,N/A,233,29.4,$11.4,LOCO LOLA
SMASH BOMBER,THU,11/10/18,3RD,(2),1.60,CCH,295,C3,17.59,17.49,17.13,N/A,233,29.2,$5.5,GO MARSHA GO
SHANLY STAR,FRI,07/09/18,3RD,(5),5.00,CCH,295,C12,17.69,17.37,17.29,N/A,723,26.4,$3.8,TUBBY KEVIE
SHANLY STAR,TUE,11/09/18,2ND,(2),0.80,OTG,310,C2,18.88,18.83,18.56,N/A,432,26.7,$5.2,MAGIC JESS LASS
SHANLY STAR,FRI,14/09/18,5TH,(5),7.80,CCH,295,C2,17.82,17.33,17.33,N/A,555,26.5,$4.8,FIERY AFFAIR
SHANLY STAR,TUE,18/09/18,1ST,(8),2.00,SOU,390,C2,22.72,22.72,22.36,5.36,111,26.7,$9.1,LONELY BAXTER
SHANLY STAR,FRI,21/09/18,5TH,(6),4.50,CCH,295,C2,18.12,17.84,17.36,N/A,355,27.1,$4.2,DIZZY BANJO
SHANLY STAR,THU,27/09/18,7TH,(7),13.20,CCH,295,C3,18.27,17.44,17.17,N/A,777,26.9,$10.4,IT'S THAT FRESH
SHANLY STAR,TUE,02/10/18,3RD,(5),1.60,SOU,390,C3,23.03,22.93,22.84,N/A,213,26.9,$7.7,DEBBIE BAXTER
SHANLY STAR,THU,11/10/18,6TH,(3),3.20,CCH,295,C3,17.69,17.49,17.13,N/A,546,26.7,$7.8,GO MARSHA GO
```

Comment: I could kiss you, thanks so much!

Now to get my head around that code :)

Comment: Actually how do I go about adding the <thead> headers in table to the top of the csv?

Comment: @user3170725 Updated with a header.

Comment: @user3170725 In case you are not familiar with list comprehensions, that's what the `[x.get_text() for x in list]` syntax is called if you need to look up how it works.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm very new to python, sometimes I find the documentation quite confusing. But yes you are right I need to really understand the modules etc that I try to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting both columns in a single writerow call, like

```
writer.writerow([n.get_text(), t.get_text()])
```

Comment: Hmm nah same thing is happening